# Is there a way to debug code in VsCode initiated with Vite?

Tags: vscode-debugger, vite

My dev team configured a Node.js project with TypeScript to use Vite as dev server, using the npm script panel of VsCode.
Is there a way to attach the debugger into this Vite server so we can debug the TSX code within the editor?

Comment: I have a similar problem with Snowpack. Cannot figure out how to configure VSCode. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66221405/how-to-setup-pathmapping-in-vscode-to-debug-a-snowpack-application

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Go to the debug tab and click "create debug.json".

Then adapt the **url** port to use 4000 if you want to use the Vite plugin for VSCode. Or 3000 if you run it with `yarn dev`, `npm run dev` or `vite` from your console.

I also had to adapt the **webRoot** as I've created an app folder which is my root folder.

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:4000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/app"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If that doesn't work, try changing the webRoot to be the directory where your 'Vue.app' file is located. Or if that doesn't work, put the directory where your index.html file is located. One of these two should work.

Comment: then how to debug a vite plugin source code? this is not works

Comment: Am I correct that launching a Chrome session in this way (which is outdated) makes the Chrome Vue Devtools unavailable?

Comment: Apparently it should be possible to have two debuggers attached at the same time, however I'm not sure if it works with this setup.  https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-63/#multi-client

Comment: What is the "Debug tab"? I have the debug console, but there's nothing where one can click in order to generate a file.

Comment: This does not work at all. The correct type is `chrome` and the correct `url` is the URL of your app e.g. `http://localhost:5174`. Then, with `"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"`, it debugs correctly.

Comment: This does not work perfectly for me. During debugging, VS Code is showing files like `localhost:4000\main.js?t=123456789` to me which are not associated with the original JS file and which are also not syntax-highlighted.

Comment: What's the difference between `"pwa-chrome"` and `"chrome"` for the `type` property?

Answer (score 12):

I write another answer, because the ones that are below were incomplete for me.

First, paste in your launch.json file this code:

```json
{
   "version":"0.2.0",
   "configurations":[
      {
         "type":"pwa-chrome",
         "request":"launch",
         "name":"Launch Chrome against localhost",
         "url":"http://localhost:4000",
         "webRoot":"${workspaceFolder}/app"
      }
   ]
}
```

Then go to package.json, and add this to your dev command:

```
"dev": "vite --port 4000"
```

Then you run the command `npm run dev` and finally you can press F5 to start debugging.

Comment: The thing that worked for me:
1. Point `webRoot` to `/src` which contains my app logic.
2. `"dev": "vite --port 5173"` in `package.json` which matches port of `"url"` in _launch.json_

Answer (score 11):

The previous answer is for debugging in Chrome, if you prefer Firefox, here's the debug.json.

```json
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "firefox",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "vuejs: firefox",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
    }
  ]
}
```

**Very important:** the `"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",` needs to point the the directory where your 'Vue.app' file is located. If that doesn't work, put the directory where your 'index.html' file is located. One of these two should work.

[image]

Further info can be found in this discussion on the official Vite GitHub repo: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/4065

Comment: `Vue.app` file 

Comment: This answer seems Vue specific. I can't see anything in the original question mentioning the use of Vue

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution that works!!!
See this reddit link: [Solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/12xu4ks/comment/jhk84gt/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Paste this in your launch.json file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug App",
            "url": "http://localhost:5173",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "webpack:///./src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
            },
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
            ],
            "sourceMaps": true
        }
    ]
}
```

And then in package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --port 5173 --host",
```

Results:

[image: Breakpoints]

[image: Debugger]

[image: Inline debugging]

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem was that the breakpoints were not binding. The debugger was somehow looking for the URL pattern to match the local file path. So, I added a `base` tag to my `vite.config.js` file like this:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    base: `/my-web-app/`,
    plugins: [react()],
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This took me a while to discover, so I think it might also help someone else out there! If you're debugging a Vue 3 application using Vite and you can't hit breakpoints set in `src/router/index.js` or `src/store/index.js`, that's because the very first few lines in those files are being rewritten by the Vue plugin of Vite and VS Code fails to match the content hashes of the local files against the ones produced by the browser. To make it work with those files, you can set the field [enableContentValidation](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/blob/main/OPTIONS.md#enablecontentvalidation-4) to `false` in the `launch.json` config as the following:

```json
{
  "preLaunchTask": "task: dev",
  "name": "chrome",
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "url": "http://localhost:5173",
  "enableContentValidation": false,
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
  "pathMapping": {"url": "/src/", "path": "${webRoot}/"}
}
```