# How to setup pathMapping in VSCode to debug a Snowpack application

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, snowpack

I'm evaluating [Snowpack](https://www.snowpack.dev/) for building my JavaScript project. However, VSCode and the [Debugger for Chrome](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome) extension cannot match the scripts on the dev server to the local source files. Because of this, breakpoints don't work. I'm not using any source maps because I'm not bundling/transforming anything, just using vanilla ES modules.

I'm using the following template: https://github.com/snowpackjs/snowpack/tree/main/create-snowpack-app/app-template-lit-element

A simplified directory layout of the project is:

```
public/
  index.html
src/
  index.js
```

Now when I start the Snowpack dev server it serves the files using the following layout, which is quite different:

```
index.html
dist/
  index.js
```

I tried the following launch configuration in VSCode, but it does not work, i.e., it cannot match the javascript files:

```
{
  "name": "Launch localhost",
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "url": "http://localhost:8080/",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/public",
  "pathMapping": {
    "/dist": "${workspaceFolder}/src"
  }
}
```

The `pathMapping` property has very scant documentation, and I'm wondering whether it's working at all.

Any ideas?

**Update:**

The lit-element example seems to use babel for transpiling, but even with transpiling disabled the problem persists. This is more a VSCode problem, not a Snowpack problem.

Comment: It sounds like snowpack is still doing some transpiling or bundling. Enabling sourcemaps in the snowpack config should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

To create an output you would like to have please configure mount option for snowpack config, experiment with this config to get the result you need.

```
  mount: {
   public: '/',
   src: '/src',
  },
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting workaround. However, VSCode is still unable to match the sources. When I add a "debugger" statement to the source, the Breakpoints panel shows that the file is: app-root.js at "/localhost:8080/src" (no http:// !). When I add a breakpoint (the red circle) to a local source file, it is app-root.js at "src".